# Attached to Detached Navigation Issue

Tags: javascript, animation, navigation, scroll

I am currently building my personal portfolio and, not having a lot of practical knowledge in javascript, but having gone through a lot a tutorials, I decided to try to implement something I saw elsewhere: A detachable navigation.

Using this site, http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/detachable-navigation/, as a reference I set about creating my detaching navigation; however, something went horribly wrong.

For one, the header will automatically align to the left rather than returning to its default position.

Second, although you can't yet see it implemented, I wanted the social icons to show up in the navigation once they were scrolled past using an animation. That bit of code was so convoluted that I scrapped it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use Bootstrap? It has this built in already: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

1. Download bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip
2. Add the bootsrap Javascript and CSS to your page.
3. In your HTML, add the following DIV:

You can change the div to fit your needs.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Honest answer: because I have no idea how to use it. I'll check it out and try to get it down, but I've never used Bootstrap or any other library, besides jQuery. And I wasn't always certain of myself with that. Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It's pretty simple: Include the Bootstrap JS, and the Bootstrap CSS, then define your navigation like they specify. I'll edit my post to give an exact outline on how to do this.